# SharePoint 2019 content organizer rule automation

Tags: sharepoint-server, content, content-organizer-rule

Greeting all,
I created some content organizer rules, and it works when I manually put the column value and submit.
I have a OCR engine and tagging application. The tagging application tag the content column value.
But the document still sit in Drop off Library. Is there any way I can automate the document submission process?
Thank you in advance.

Farook Golam

Answer (score 0):

You could use workflow to set field value automatically.
[image]